# UISegmentedControl, touch target too low?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Is it just me (and my boss), or is the touch target too low on the UISegmentedControl?  That is, it feels like you have to tap slightly below the control to get it to switch selections, or at least the lower half of it, not the center or upper half.

I'm testing this on an actual iPad, running iOS 8.1

I'm not an iOS user, so not very familiar with the actual OS, so not sure where I can find other built-in apps that use this native control to see if it is just my app or other apps also.  I am able to recreate in a simple test project though, with nothing special going on.  I can't change the height of the control, not in IB anyway, and even if I could, I don't really want it taller, I just want the "tap target" to be in the "correct" location.

Sorry if duplicate question, I couldn't find any info on this subject... possibly nobody is using this control, maybe for reasons like this.

To make sure this is a programming question... if not just me, what can I do to fix it, short of just not using this control?

Comment: Seems as if it's more of a human ui question. To be honest, I don't use them too much, but back in the days of iOS 6 (and maybe even 5) it was ok. You can try to create a dummy app with only one segmented control to test the situation, and see if it's a bug or if you just have to live with it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Lior.  I am able to recreate with a simple project, so either a bug or "by design".  I'm hoping that doesn't mean "I have to live with it" though, hopefully some SO user out there has a simple work-around for it... maybe some adjustment to the frame or content rectangle or "layers", don't really know, but fingers crossed.